# How can I access a array of labels on a 2nd function, which were created in a previous function? Win Forms App.NET

Tags: function, variables, call, global

I created an array of labels which are called and put on specified location on screen ( when I press a button / when I access that function ). How can i dispose those variables/labelarrays with another button ( in another function )? I mention that I declared labelarray as global at the beginning.

```
Public Class MyForm

Dim p_global As Integer
Dim labelarray() As Label

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
...
    p_global = p

    Dim labelarray(p) As Label
    For index As Integer = 0 To p Step 1

        labelarray(index) = New Label With {
            .Name = String.Format("labelpart_", index.ToString),
            .AutoSize = False,
            .Size = New Drawing.Size(scal_Part_Width, scal_Part_Height),
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        }
...

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Index = 0 To p_global Step 1

        labelarray(Index).Dispose()

    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

It gives me an error on  **labelarray(Index).Dispose()** "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Can someone explain me please how can I call those exactly labelarray which I created in the 1st function?

EDIT: Apparently It works as a charm. I just needed to put a value on calling the global arraylabel() -> to arraylabel(999). I deleted the  **Dim labelarray(p) As Label** from the local function Button1_Click.

**Here's the code that worked for me**

```
Public Class MyForm

Dim p_global As Integer
Dim labelarray(999) As Label

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
...
    p_global = p

    For index As Integer = 0 To p Step 1

        labelarray(index) = New Label With {
            .Name = String.Format("labelpart_", index.ToString),
            .AutoSize = False,
            .Size = New Drawing.Size(scal_Part_Width, scal_Part_Height),
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        }
... 

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Index = 0 To p_global Step 1

        labelarray(Index).Dispose()

    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Question: Is there a possibility for the global labelarray() to be to be initialized with a local input? I tried labelarray(p_global) but it gives me an error, so I put inside 999 elements and hope that the user will not exceed this limit.

Comment: You can check with IsDisposed before Dispose()

Comment: I searcher for IsDisposed and it was in my understanding that new vb versions already have this method as default?  
Anyway, I found a solution and now it works, although can you give me an answer for the last question in edit? ( i would really appreciate )

Comment: Can you use the List instead of the Array?
Dim lablelList As New List(Of Label)

Comment: nope. I think I need to create a private void function so that when I try to initiate my arraylist , i can use my input variable. Right now because the global variable is at the beginning, the program goes in cascade and take as array elements whatever variable is at that moment in it.